# log4j log file relative path, CONSOLE APPLICATION(jar)

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I'm using Spring in a Console java application. I'm using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load database details, and it works flawlessly:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:/appdata/configs/myapplication/connection.properties" />  
</bean>
```

So the root dir will be relative to where the jar is located. I need the same functionality with log4j.properties

```
log4j.appender.file.File=/appdata/configs/myapplication/myapplication-log.log
```

How can I achieve this without defining environment variables?

Comment: Do you want your log files to get created at the root directory of your App or some absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried it like this:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=\\appdata\\configs\\myapplication\\myapplication-log.log
```

And it works fine.